# Listed parent company on resume and background check, check couldn’t verify employer

Tags: background-check, onboarding

I got an exciting offer from a company that I really want to work for. Going through the background check now and have a start date set up. At my current company, it is a subsidiary of a parent company and I listed the parent company on the resume and background check application.
Got a respond from the background check company that they couldn’t verify employer and to provide information like W-2. I sent them W-2 of the company but I noticed that the company name on the W-2 is the subsidiary and that there’s nowhere in the W-2 that has the parent name in it. Should I be worried? I’m starting to worry that it’ll flag up or fail the background check. Will they manually check to make sure that the companies are related or how do they handle cases like this? Only worried because I already put in my two weeks and the start date is coming up.

Comment: What is stopping you from calling them and explain? Or an email? Also, next time onwards, do not omit information that causes confusions.

Comment: I would expect that any background check company worth its fees would be able to follow the company hierarchy in this case, but it wouldn't hurt to let them know

Comment: Yea, I called the background check company and they said they couldn’t do anything, even after submitting my documentation, they weren’t able to verify based on the results. My company is pretty small so I assume that there could be some complication but an explanation to the new employer could probably do. The background check also stated there were discrepancies in my education start date when in fact it’s correct so I guess it wasn’t that great of a check.

Answer (score 6):

Call the background check company and explain the situation. Afterwards, you can send an email for confirmation to be sure it is handled appropriately. I do not assume you'll fail a background check because of this, but that is of course impossible for anybody to say with certainty.